# How to user Right-To-Left for RTL languages like Arabic in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, arabic, right-to-left, arabic-support

I already looked through all of the similar questions at stack overflow. I am sorry if this is a duplicate. If it is, I will gladly delete this since I already have my answer.

I am developing an application in Swift that supports English and Arabic languages. I added AutoLayout constraints (leading and trailing, not left and right as pointed out by some answers). I have the strings localized.

The user has the option to change their language INSIDE the application. I am talking inside the application, not about the whole phone. He could have had his phone language be Arabic but chose English as his application language.

Can someone help me with how to proceed with that? Some answers pointed to use `semanticContentAttribute` by forcing it right to left, and some did not.

I want my application to be mirrored, all of it. It includes collectionViews, TableViews, etc ...

Example:

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the app is actually localized for both English and Arabic, there is nothing to do; reversal of the interface when the app switches between RTL and LTR script languages is automatic.

Comment: `semanticContentAttribute` is a good start. However, your custom components (e.g. custom table view cells) have to actually support both directions. That usually means using the correct horizontal constraints.

Comment: Make sure you use leading and trailing constraints (not left and right). It's rare you ever actually want to use left and right. For the rest, there is not much you need to do.